# Querying postgres for distinct values of A where B has all values of a given set

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two columns like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

How do I query in postgres "Give me the distinct values of A such that have B contains both [1, 2] when A is a constant?" The expected result of such a query is A = [1, 2] from the simple table above.

I have been reading the postgres documentation and have written some queries, but I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

This is coming from a ManyToMany relation's join table and I am also thinking about revisiting the relation there -- perhaps I am looking at this in a more complicated way than it needs to be. But I have use cases for both query sides, e.g.:

"Given a set of B, give me all instances of A that contain all given values of B"

as well as

"Given a set of A, give me all the instances of B that are related to A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common query, and one canonical approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT A
FROM yourTable
WHERE B IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 2;
```

For the exact case of checking for only 2 distinct B values, we could also have written the `HAVING` clause as:

```
HAVING MIN(B) <> MAX(B)
```

and this might be *sargable* (i.e. can use an index on the `B` column).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Appreciate the help! I am going to keep examining my use case as well, as well as my other architectural layers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT "Column A"
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY "Column A"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "Column B" IN (1, 2) THEN "Column B" END) = 2;
```

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "Column B" IN (1, 2) THEN "Column B" END) counts the distinct values of "Column B" that are either 1 or 2.

The = 2 condition ensures that the group has both values 1 and 2 in "Column B".
This query will return the distinct values of "Column A" for which all specified values of B (1 and 2) are present.